# How to display folder size in file explorer?

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon

Inside `pantheon-files` folders do not show its size, like files do.

[image: No folder size]

However in properties of the folder size is shown:

[image: Folder properties]

Is there a way to display folder size directly in file explorer?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. But do you have seen this in any other Linux File Manager? (just curious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devs should correct me, but I don't think this is possible. I think you will have to file a bug report on launchpad.

The reason will probably be that it requires a lot of disk reading to find the disk usage of everey directory. For an extreme example opening `/`: It will have to recursively read the entire filesystem.